# android studio not working 3.1.3

Tags: android-studio, android-studio-3.1.3

```
7/17/2018
10:39 م Plugin Error
            Problems found loading plugins:
            Plugin "Android Games" was not loaded: required plugin "Android Support" is disabled.
            Plugin "Android NDK Support" was not loaded: required plugin "Android Support" is disabled.
            Plugin "Android APK Support" was not loaded: required plugin "Android Support" is disabled.
            Plugin "Google Developers Samples" was not loaded: required plugin "Android Support" is disabled.
            Plugin "Google Cloud Tools For Android Studio" was not loaded: required plugin "Android Support" is disabled.
            Plugin "Test Recorder" was not loaded: required plugin "Android Support" is disabled.
            Plugin "Firebase Testing" was not loaded: required plugin "Android Support" is disabled.
            Plugin "Google Services" was not loaded: required plugin "Android Support" is disabled.
            Plugin "Firebase Services" was not loaded: required plugin "Android Support" is disabled.
            Plugin "App Links Assistant" was not loaded: required plugin "Android Support" is disabled.
            Plugin "Fire... (show balloon)

10:40 م Error Loading Project: Cannot load 3 facets Details...

10:40 م Plugins Suggestion
            Plugin supporting features (Run 
Configuration[AndroidRunConfigurationType], Facet[android, android-gradle]) is currently disabled.
            Enable plugins...
            Ignore Unknown Features
```

Answer (score 2):

Go to File, Then Settings->Plugin-> .........

here you will see the  list  of all plugin

```
Android Games
Android NDK Support
Android APK Support
..
..
```

plugin for those you are seeing this warning "Android Support" is disabled, they will be in red color , others will be in black ..

what you have to do is .... un tick and tick again for those you are getting exception  and click on apply changes and restart studio 
it will work